# Need Help on Java Signatures

Tags: java

I recently started learning the java programming language and I need some help on this question. Given a class file that declares the following field as an arrayList private `private ArrayList<String> files;` write a header (signature) for a method that lists all members of this collection.  Call your method listAllFiles. My current attempt is something like this.

```
private listAllFiles(ArrayList<String>);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are omitting a return type from your method. All Java methods must return a type or `void`.

If your method simply lists all files to a `String Object` then it could return a String:

```
public String listAllFiles()
```

If it lists all files to System.out it could return `void`:

```
public void listAllFiles()
```

Alternatively it could return a copy of the `private ArrayList<String>` (thus leaving the private variable immutable to clients):

```
public List<String> listAllFiles()
```

Note that your method probably ought to be `public` to allow clients to make use of it... This depends largely on requirements though, and it might be appropriate for the method to be `private` to the `Class`.

Note, as pointed out by @Thilo in the comments, if you are returning a `List` you should "program to the interface", returning a List rather than a specific type of List, thus allowing you to change out your actual `List` implementation if/when requirements change.

Answer (score 2):

If the method just prints out something, then the return type would be `void` (nothing):

```
public void listAllFiles(){
   // no need to pass in the string list, because we can do
   for (String l: this.files){
     // ..
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method has to have first the access level (e.g. `private`, `protected`, `public` or nothing for the *default* level) and after that it has to define what it returns, so I assume from the description this will be nothing (`void`), you don't need any parameters if you have the field in this class:

```
private void listAllFiles();
```